# How to display state variables access inside map loop as horizontal tabs in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, mapping, react-bootstrap

I want to display my variables mapped in horizontal tabs. When I mapped my state variables to a tab each, it automatically set the tab in a vertical column. How can I circumvent around this?

```
 render() {
if (!this.state.customerList)
  return (<p>Loading data</p>)
return (<div className="addmargin">
  <div className="row">
    {
    this.state.customerList.data.map((customer) => (
      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTab} onSelect={this.handleSelect} className="centeralign"
      onClick={() => this.setState({selectedCustomer: customer.id})}>
      <Tab eventKey={customer.id} title={customer.name}></Tab>
      </Tabs>
    ))
    }
</div>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <CustomerDetails val={this.state.selectedCustomer}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output: [A vertical column with my 3 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH4NM.png)

There is probably no issue with my css. If I were to hardcode in,

```
  render() {
if (!this.state.customerList)
  return (<p>Loading data</p>)
return (<div className="addmargin">
  <div className="row">
    {

      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTab} className="centeralign">
      <Tab eventKey="1" title="John"> </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey="2" title="William"> </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey="3" title="Harry"> </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

Then the output is [3 horizontal tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFyyu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
render() {
if (!this.state.customerList)
  return (<p>Loading data</p>)
return (
<div className="addmargin">
    <div className="row">
       <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTab} onSelect={this.handleSelect} 
        className="centeralign">
        {
        this.state.customerList.data.map((customer) => (
             return <Tab eventKey={customer.id} title={customer.name}></Tab>
        ))
        }
        </Tabs>
    </div>
</div>)
```

Issue is that you are using map function for Tabs, but Tabs should be outside the map function and map should return individual Tab components.

Comment: Hi @chandan_kr_jha, thank you for the suggestion. The tabs now appear horizontally but when I clicked on each tab, the panels associated with the tab no longer load. I added in the onClick in the Tab components ( <Tab eventKey={customer.id} title={customer.name} onClick={() => this.setState({selectedCustomer: customer.id})}></Tab> ) but nothing changes onClick. What alternatives would you suggest? (I have edited the posted question above to include in the latter part of the code about what the onClick is meant for)

Comment: For Tabs you have activeKey as this.state.activeTab, there is no need to add onClick on Tab, you have to set activeTab in state when onSelect function is called

handleSelect = (key) => {
 this.setState({
  activeTab: key
 })
}

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I have that and it works, allowing me to switch between horizontal tabs. However, in order to access the information associated with each tab, I have to this.setState({selectedCustomer: customer.id}) somewhere. If you were to refer to the first paragraph of code, I have another component called CustomerDetails that need a variable this.state.selectedCustomer. I tried to setState for selectedCustomer in the tab but it does not work. I am not sure where else I can setState for selectedCustomer after mapping.